# Spring boot War file not running in websphere 8.5

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

I devoloped simple spring boot application with spring and generated WAR file deployed on Webspher but it is not working.
The same code working on Tomcat or other server wokring fine.If posible please provide the code github repository.I tried with all posible case but still i am facing the issues.
this is my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>ClientDemo4</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ClientDemo4</name>
    <description>nSure Validation Service</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <!-- <start-class>com.demo</start-class> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>12.1.0.2</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>ClientDemo4</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is my main class

```
 @ComponentScan
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.kgisl" })
    @OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Towing App", version = "v1", description = "Towing Application", license = @License(name = "MIT License", url = "https://github.com/bchen04/springboot-swagger-rest-api/blob/master/LICENSE"), contact = @Contact(url = "https://in.linkedin.com/company/kgislgss", name = "")))
    //@SpringBootApplication
    public class CommonValidationsApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(CommonValidationsApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

This is servel class

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CommonValidationsApplication.class);
    }

}
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
    public class BasicController {
        
        
        @GetMapping(value="/test")
        public String testMethod(String str)
        {
            return "You are input is:"+str;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the failure you're seeing?

Comment: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method &amp;quot&#59;org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/DataObjectPropertyBinder.bindProperty&amp;#40&#59;Ljava/lang/String&amp;#59&#59;Lorg/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable&amp;#59&#59;&amp;#41&#59;Ljava/lang/Object&amp;#59&#59;&amp;quot&#59; during creation of